# Generator always returning same value

Tags: python, file, io

I have a function that reads a file line by line and returns it as a list of the words. Since the file is very large, i would like to make it a generator.

Here is the function:

```py
def tokenize_each_line(file):
   with open(file, 'r') as f:
      for line in f:
         yield line.split()
```

However, everytime i call `next(tokenize_each_line())`, it always returns the first line of the file. I guess this is not the expected behavior for generators. Instead, i'd like the function to return the next line.

Comment: You're initialising a new generator each time. The way to achieve what you are looking for is to do something like `gen = tokenize_each_line()` once, and then repeatedly call `next(gen)`

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem! Feel free to leave an answer for acceptance.

Comment: Maybe your actual code looks different, but `next(tokenize_each_line())` should raise an exception (`TypeError`) since `file` isn't an optional argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the function `tokenize_each_line()` returns a *newly-initialized* generator. So `next(tokenize_each_line())` initializes a generator and makes it yield its first item (the first line of the file).

Instead, initialize the generator, hold a reference to it, and call `next` on it according to your requirements.

For example:

```
gen = tokenize_each_line('myfile.txt')

# just as an example of how you might want to use the generator
words = []
while len(words) < 1000:
    words += next(gen)
```

Comment: Why impose a limit? Also, if there are fewer than 1000 lines in the file, a StopIteration exception will be raised which you are not accounting for

Comment: Quite true, but fundamentally this is a toy example, and the details of what happens don't have a direct bearing on fixing the questioner's problem. My motivation was to sketch an example which isn't better achieved simply by iterating over the generator in a `for` statement without ever needing to hold a reference to it. If you wanted all the words in the file without a limit, you'd just do a `for` loop and not have an explicit `next`, so that would be a less direct illustration of how to fix the questioner's problem here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use *next()* in the manner shown in your question, you will restart the generator every time *next()* is called.

Without making any changes to your *tokenize_each_line()* you could use a *for* loop like this:

```
for words in tokenize_each_line('foo.txt'):
   print(words)
```